# Positioning an icon on the border of a "dynamic" div

Tags: css

## Context

I'm trying to show an icon `icon-delete-2a.png` on the border of a `div`.

- I can't seem to bring the icon forward using `z-index`.
- Furthermore I am also looking at 'the best way' to dynamically position the icon using CSS. When `innerText` would equal "TestTestTest", the width of my `userItem` is adjusted, but the icon should shift to the right as well. Calculating the length of the `userItem` with JS to then adjust it's style ain't that practical.

## Related issues

Several other people asked about this, but unfortunately, the proposed solutions (setting `position: relative;` on the parent and setting `position: absolute; z-index: 1` on the child) didn't seem to resolve my issue. See:

1. [CSS - Add icon on left of border with relative position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812800/css-add-icon-on-left-of-border-with-relative-position)
2. [z-index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning)
3. [Position div on the border of another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755416/position-div-on-the-border-of-another-div)

## Minimal Working Example

```css
.useritem {
  position: relative;
  height: 15.625px;
  padding-left: 6.25px;
  padding-right: 6.25px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff0000;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.icon_delete {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7.5px;
  left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.useritem:focus {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;       
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

[contenteditable] {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="useritems">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="useritem" id="Location_Explore_UserItem_00" contenteditable="true" style="border: 2px solid black; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Test<img class="icon_delete" src="https://i.ibb.co/jTQckJm/icon-delete-2a.png" width="15" height="15">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It does not answer your question, but you may want to use pseudo-elements for this kind of "icons". Instead of having `<img/>` each time, you could use `.useritem::after` with background of your icon on it.

Comment: @SeeoX: thanks for the proposed suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of `overflow` attribute. Set the `overflow` value to `initial` or `scroll` on `.useritem` and you will see the icon outside.

```css
.useritem {
  position: relative;
  height: 15.625px;
  padding-left: 6.25px;
  padding-right: 6.25px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff0000;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  
  overflow: initial;
}

.icon_delete {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7.5px;
  right: -8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.useritem:focus {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;       
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

[contenteditable] {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="useritems">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="useritem" id="Location_Explore_UserItem_00" contenteditable="true" style="border: 2px solid black; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Test<img class="icon_delete" src="https://i.ibb.co/jTQckJm/icon-delete-2a.png" width="15" height="15">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you could help me out on the second part of my question as well? I'd like the icon to move dynamically when the `useritem` div becomes larger.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can adjust it using `right` position on `.icon_delete`. There, in the past, you have put the icon using `left` position. And change it to `right` position and it will work. @user1098973

Answer (score 2):

You have used "overflow" css that's why it's not showing. Remove overflow css you can see your icon position.